# Admob website Stuck on infinite loading Screen

Tags: admob, adsense

I don't know if I can post this type of problem here or not.
But I'm facing a loading screen problem in Admob Website in the console it's giving me these errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+0001 | create:1:6

Script from “https://apps.admob.com/cam/JsPrefetch?f.sid=6304703823020497000” was blocked 
because of a disallowed MIME type (“image/gif”).
```

I'm facing this issue more then a month, Google forums not helping in this case.

I'm using Firefox 110.0
I tried Chrome and Opera Browsers.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, stop the Ad-block extension. then the loading screen disappeared

Comment: Worked! Somehow I find this quite funny lol

Comment: Great, it does work

Answer (score 14):

Disabling the adblock extensions worked for me. With that, the forever loading of admob page stopped happening.